# Installed 'Microsoft VS code' in custom directory now I can't use Go support

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've installed Microsoft VS Code in another partition (Drive D) on my Windows 10 system. I prefer to keep Microsoft VS Code in another partition away from Windows.

My goal is to install the GO extension from Microsoft. The link to the extension is here.

[Click here to visit the source of the repository to the go extension.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go.git)

The following error occurs when I attempt to install the GO extension through the Extension dialog in the Microsoft VS Code application.

The Error:

> Failed to run "go env" to find GOPATH as the "go" binary cannot be
> found in either GOROOT(undefined) or PATH (
>
> C:\Windows\system32;
>
> C:\Windows;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;
>
> **a gfx card driver directory here**;
>
> **a gfx card driver directory here**;
>
> C:\Users\ **My username left out**
> \AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
>
> )

I suspect that the cause is the fact that I installed Microsoft VS Code in another partition. I've also mentioned this at the beginning of my question. I've explained the steps that I took to find the solution below:

First I examined the location of the go resource. It seems that my resource is placed in the right folder (the folder of my installation.

> D:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\go

Than I tried a simple command through the commands by pressing **`ctrl+shift+p`** and then typing go:Current GOPATH. the error message

> command go.goroot not found

Then I thought of testing out if I can run a basic go file. I searched for a simple example and came across [this site.](https://gobyexample.com/hello-world). So, I've created a project folder and added the file Hello.go in the folder **D:\VS_Projects\GO_Helloworld** Then I placed the hello world program in it. The program is shown below

```
package main


import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

In the microsoft vs code powershell terminal I check if the terminal is in the right folder. It shows 'PS D:\VS_Projects\GO_Helloworld>' so that should be right. I run the following command:

```
go run Hello.go
```

The following error is shown in the terminal:

> on, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
> , or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - go run Hello.go
> - ~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (go:String) [], Comma      ndNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I'm currently thinking of steps to take as described by ['ramya-rao-a'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595#issuecomment-517076042) and ['AndreiD'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595#issuecomment-520515437) on [this github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595) in the powershell terminal.

[On stackoverflow I was privately suggested to post this question on super user](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59694910/edit). So I did :D.

Let me know if you have an answer to my problem. Best regards!

Comment: Why did you install VS Code in a non-standard location? It's not particularly large.

Comment: I agree with you on that. It's very lightweight software with very light projects in terms of storage. An exception is large projects. (debatable in the case of VS code)


But I've other reasons to use the non-standard location.


Firstly, I like to keep my developer software separated from my personal files and games on the D partition. On my laptop my drive got really messy due to usage of multiple IDE's during my college time. 


And lastly, I won't have to deal with [folder restrictions when I use Git](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2203). Correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely installing the Go Extension from Microsoft is not enough for you to be able to run/debug code. You need other utilities and tools that the extension relies on to run properly. See them here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-tools-that-the-Go-extension-depends-on

Edit: You also need a Go Compiler - the most important part. This is not included in the Go Extension from Microsoft. https://golang.org/doc/install

This is what the OP said worked for them:

> **Edit (or enclosure) by DeliciousCookiedev:**
>
> I succesfully installed some of the required utilities and tools by accident.
>   I merely had in mind to manually practice with the go compiler and use vscode as a standalone code editor. 
>   The following steps below lead to a succesful go operation of powershell terminal in vscode.
>
> 1. Installed the golang compiler on my d-drive
> 2. Set the environment variable GOPATH to `D:/custom-folder`
> 3. created a folder called `custom-folder/src/hello` as the [project workspace folder to start the testing process](https://golang.org/doc/install#testing)
> 4. added a [hello world script](https://golang.org/doc/install#testing) to a new file 'hello.go'
> 5. opened cmd.exe as administrator
> 6. executed command `D:` and then `cd custom-folder/src/hello` in cmd.exe
> 7. executed command `go build` and then `hello`. The terminal showed: 'hello world'
> 8. started vscode and then opened the same hello project I just tested through task window
>
>    'file > open folder (shortkey ctrl+k or ctrl+o)'
> 9. then I clicked on the file hello.go A dialog window in the in the right lower corner showed message. It said something like **'missing required go extensions. Would you like to install them now?'**
> 10. I clicked on 'ok'
> 11. then the tools were installed "  gocode, gopkgs, go-outline, gocode-gomod, godef, goreturns, golint"
> 12. Then I succesfully tested my hello.go file through the powershell terminal in vscode with command `go run hello.go`

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for your help! So far, I've installed the go compiler and succesfully tested the go compiler. Now for the more difficult part, installing the other utilities and tools. I need to find out where they should be located. If I find the answer, then I'll let you know. But I thought it would be more efficient to tell you in advance since probably know what to do with the extensions precisely.

Comment: I found **'a'** way for installing the tools. I enclosed my steps in your post. Thanks for your help Sam

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful is choco is your package manager :

Try to install go compiler with choco :

```
choco install golang 

# if you have proxy registry
# choco install golang --source http://nexus.local:8081/repository/nuget-choco
```

---

Return back now to Visual Code, Create any file main.go , save it,then Restart Visual code.

Visual Code will give the option to install ALL tools for go, cliick install All.. You should see the following in the log of the install :

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=C:\Users\yourusername\go
Installing 9 tools at C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin in module mode.
  gopkgs
  go-outline
  gotests
  gomodifytags
  impl
  goplay
  dlv
  golint
  gopls

Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\gopkgs.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\go-outline.exe) SUCCEEDED

All tools successfully installed. You are ready to Go :).
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\go-outline.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/... (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\gotests.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\gomodifytags.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/josharian/impl (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\impl.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\goplay.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\dlv.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing golang.org/x/lint/golint (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\golint.exe) SUCCEEDED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls (C:\Users\yourusername\go\bin\gopls.exe) SUCCEEDED

All tools successfully installed. You are ready to Go :).
```